# Caixa de Busca com Texto Preenchido

Tags: html5

Vou inserir a caixa de busca abaixo no texto e quero que dentro dela já fique por padrão o texto de buscas "marcas de eletrodomésticos" para que o usuário tenha que apenas clicar buscar sem precisar preencher o texto.

```
<div id="divBusca">
    <input type="text" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
    <img src="search3.png" id="btnBusca" alt="Buscar"/>
</div>
```

Como faço??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar um `value` no `input text` com o texto desejado, no caso "*marcas de eletrodomésticos*". O `value` de um campo `input text` é o texto exibido nele.

Seu código ficaria:

```html
<div id="divBusca">
   <input type="text" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar..." value="marcas de eletrodomésticos" />
   <img src="search3.png" id="btnBusca" alt="Buscar"/>
</div>
```